# Difference between Logistic Loss and Cross Entropy Loss

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, loss-function, cross-entropy

I'm confused about logistic loss and cross entropy loss in binary classification scenario. 
According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_functions_for_classification), the **logistic loss** is defined as:

[image]

where `v=y*y_hat`

The **cross entropy loss** is defined as:

[image]

From the Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_functions_for_classification):

> It's easy to check that the logistic loss and binary cross entropy loss (Log loss) are in fact the same (up to a multiplicative constant 1/log(2))

However, when I test it with some code, I found they are not the same. Here is the python code:

```
from numpy import exp
from math import log

def cross_entropy_loss(y, yp):
    return -log(1-yp) if y==0 else -log(yp)

def logistic_loss(y, yp):
    return log(1+exp(-y*yp))/log(2)

y, yp = 0, 0.3  # y= {0, 1} for cross_entropy_loss
l1 = cross_entropy_loss(y, yp)
y, yp = -1, 0.3  # y = {-1, 1} for logistic loss
l2 = logistic_loss(y, yp)
print(l1, l2, l1/l2)

y, yp = 1, 0.9
l1 = cross_entropy_loss(y, yp)
l2 = logistic_loss(y, yp)
print(l1, l2, l1/l2)
```

The output shows that neither the loss values are the same nor the ratio between them is constant:

```
0.35667494393873245 1.2325740743522222 0.2893740436056004
0.10536051565782628 0.49218100325603786 0.21406863523949665
```

Could somebody explain why they are "in fact the same"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074276/how-is-logistic-loss-and-cross-entropy-related

Comment: @ccl I've tried to understand that answer. I'm confused that the logistic loss equation in that answer is just cross entropy loss but not the one I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

In wikipedia v is defined as

v = -yf(x).

What is not defined in wikipedia is \hat{y} (i.e. the predicted label). It should be defined as (logistic function):

\hat{y} = 1/(1+exp(-f(x))).

By substituting the above definition into the logistic loss formula from the wikipedia, you should be able to recover the cross entropy loss. Please note that cross entropy loss equation (you have presented above) is formulated for y={0,1}, while the eqautions from the wikipedia article are for y={-1,1}.